Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mediapipeFacemesh') on my wordpress plugin using tensorflow.js
I have this code to superimpose an image on the face detected by he camera.
The camera is opened but the image is fixed at the top, I want it to be dynamic between the eyes of the face.
When I open the console of the camera popup, I have this error : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mediapipeFacemesh')"
there is the code :
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.try-button');

    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let glassesPath = this.getAttribute('data-glasses-path');

            // Transformer l'URL de l'image en chemin local
            glassesPath = glassesPath.replace(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/wp-content/, 'https://testt.com/wp-content');

            console.log('Chemin de l\'image des lunettes:', glassesPath);

            // Ouvrir un popup pour l'essayage de lunettes
            const popupWidth = 600;
            const popupHeight = 500;

            const left = (window.screen.width - popupWidth) / 2;
            const top = (window.screen.height - popupHeight) / 2;

            const popupFeatures = `width=${popupWidth},height=${popupHeight},left=${left},top=${top}`;

            const popup = window.open('', 'tryOnPopup', popupFeatures);

            popup.document.write(`
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Essayage de lunettes</title>
                    <style>
                        body {
                            margin: 0;
                            overflow: hidden;
                        }
                        #videoCanvas {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: 0;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                            object-fit: cover;
                        }
                        #glassesImage {
                            position: absolute;
                            width: 20%; /* Ajuster la largeur des lunettes */
                            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                            pointer-events: none;
                            z-index: 100;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <video id="videoCanvas" autoplay playsinline></video>
                    <img id="glassesImage" src="${glassesPath}" alt="Glasses Image">
                 
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@latest"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/facemesh"></script>
                    <script>


                    async function startTryOn() {
                        const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoCanvas');
                        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
                        videoElement.srcObject = stream;
                        await videoElement.play();

                        const model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
                            faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
                        );

                            const overlayCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                            overlayCanvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
                            overlayCanvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
                            overlayCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
                            overlayCanvas.style.top = '0';
                            overlayCanvas.style.left = '0';
                            overlayCanvas.style.width = '100%';
                            overlayCanvas.style.height = '100%';
                            overlayCanvas.style.objectFit = 'cover';
                            document.body.appendChild(overlayCanvas);
                            const overlayCtx = overlayCanvas.getContext('2d');

                            function drawGlasses(predictions) {
                                overlayCtx.clearRect(0, 0, overlayCanvas.width, overlayCanvas.height);

                                if (predictions.length > 0) {
                                    const prediction = predictions[0]; // Assumant un seul visage
                                    const leftEye = prediction.scaledMesh[33];
                                    const rightEye = prediction.scaledMesh[263];

                                    // Afficher les coordonnées des yeux dans la console
                                    console.log('Position du leftEye:', leftEye);
                                    console.log('Position du rightEye:', rightEye);

                                    // Calcul des dimensions et position des lunettes de manière dynamique
                                    const width = Math.abs(leftEye[0] - rightEye[0]) * 1.5;
                                    const height = width * 0.5; // Ajuster la hauteur des lunettes si nécessaire

                                    const centerX = (leftEye[0] + rightEye[0]) / 2;
                                    const centerY = (leftEye[1] + rightEye[1]) / 2;

                                    // Positionner les lunettes entre les yeux
                                    const x = centerX - width / 2;
                                    const y = centerY - height / 2;

                                    overlayCtx.save();
                                    overlayCtx.translate(centerX, centerY);
                                    overlayCtx.rotate(getFaceAngle(leftEye, rightEye)); // Ajuster la rotation si nécessaire
                                    overlayCtx.drawImage(document.getElementById('glassesImage'), -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
                                    overlayCtx.restore();
                                }
                            }

                            function getFaceAngle(leftEye, rightEye) {
                                return Math.atan2(rightEye[1] - leftEye[1], rightEye[0] - leftEye[0]);
                            }

                            function renderPredictions() {
                                model.estimateFaces({ input: videoElement }).then(predictions => {
                                    drawGlasses(predictions);
                                    requestAnimationFrame(renderPredictions);
                                });
                            }

                            renderPredictions();
                        }

                        startTryOn();
                    </script>
                </body>
                </html>
            `);

            popup.focus();
        });
    });
});

I try to import via cdn but nothing works.
How can i fix it ?
